French weekdays in R
If I type:
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "fr_FR.UTF-8")

data.frame(day_number=1:7) %>% 
     mutate(day_of_week  = wday(day_number, label = TRUE))

Then the first day of the week appears to be Sunday (Dim), when French people normally use Monday as first day of the week. Is there a way to encode this with setlocale?

See the help for ?wday:

week_start
day on which week starts following ISO conventions: 1 means Monday and 7 means Sunday (default). When label = FALSE and week_start = 7, the number returned for Sunday is 1, for Monday is 2, etc. When label = TRUE, the returned value is a factor with the first level being the week start (e.g. Sunday if week_start = 7). You can set lubridate.week.start option to control this parameter globally.

So you can use
wday(day_number, label = TRUE, week_start = 1)

or run
options(lubridate.week.start = 1)

and have that be the default.
